# Which characters switch between weapons 1 and 2?

Tags: overwatch

Torbjorn has a gun, but can use the Next Weapon and Previous Weapon buttons to switch between it and a hammer, or directly select one of the two weapons by using the Equip Weapon 1 or Equip Weapon 2 buttons.

Is he the only one in Overwatch that's like that?

I do not remember a second weapon for any other characters except Mercy, but she almost never uses her side gun because her job is to heal her pal.

So only Torb and Mercy right?

Comment: Probably getting downvoted for general reference (not doing research), but one would have had to either know this off the top of their head, or check multiple pages. Not upvoting, but downvote seems a little harsh.

Comment: Even if I look that up, I will have to check the hero one by one to make sure. Even if I know, I would have to ask here to make sure.

Comment: Gave you an upvote after I thought more about the effort/experience needed to determine this. -8 is absurd.

Answer (score 3):

Some of the other heroes have an alternate fire on their main gun, but those are the only two with an actual different weapon they have to switch to, yes.

Torbjorn and Mercy both switch weapons using the D-pad on console, which is mapped to the "Next Weapon" action by default. No other character does. The Previous Weapon and two Equip Weapon buttons are not mapped by default on the console controller.

I reviewed the [heroes on the wiki](http://overwatch.gamepedia.com/Heroes), just to be sure.

Comment: Doesn't D.Va meet the criteria of the question? She has a sidearm... and a mech suit.

Comment: @Ellesedil D.Va can't freely switch back and forth the same way Mercy and Torbjorn do. When she's out of her mech she has only a pistol, and when she's in her mech she has only the cannons. Also, Mercy and Torbjorn switch with the same button, which no other character uses.

Comment: Hmm, it wasn't clear that the question is about switching weapons adhoc like that. I just saw "2 kinds of weapons" and ran with it.

Comment: I think I make the question more clear. The issue is pressing that 1-2 button.

Comment: @JimThio I play this game on console, so indicating PC buttons doesn't really help.

Answer (score 0):

Torbjorn with Forge Hammer rivet gun and mercy with Caduceus blaster and Caduceus staff but if you talked about which character  guns could change into different guns it would be a different story